# Declaration of interface in middle of classes tree (C++)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface, declaration

Please look at inheritance:

```
interface IArray
{
   virtual unsigned __int8* GetAddress() const = 0;

   virtual unsigned int GetItemCount() const = 0;

   virtual unsigned int GetItemSize() const = 0;
};

template<class T>
class CustomArrayT : public IArray
{
public:

   virtual unsigned __int8* GetAddress() const;

   virtual unsigned int GetItemCount() const;

   virtual unsigned int GetItemSize() const;


   T& GetItem(unsigned int index);
};

interface IFloatArray : public CustomArrayT<float>
{
   virtual IFloatArray* GetCompressedData() const = 0;
};

class ShannonFloatArray : public IFloatArray
{
public:

   virtual IFloatArray* GetCompressedData() const;
};

class FourierFloatArray : public IFloatArray
{
public:

   virtual IFloatArray* GetCompressedData() const;
};

class MickyMouseFloatArray : public IFloatArray
{
public:

   virtual IFloatArray* GetCompressedData() const;
};
```

Main goal of the question is inheritance **IFloatArray -> CustomArrayT**: interface inherits some none abstract class. I do not want to support multiple inheritance. But I need all downtree classes has functionality of class CustomArrayT and implementing interface IFloatArray.

What pros and cons of such tree?

How could it be done by another way? Maybe some pattern?

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
template<class T>
class IArray {
public:
  virtual int size() const=0;
  virtual T map(int index) const=0;
};
```

All the pointers are just unnecessary.

Comment: Good idea. But I need pointers to be accessible and base interface not to be templated. +1 for mapping;)

Comment: Maybe consider placing the array and the pointers to separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your heirarchy is exactly what is the IArray interface for?

If you wished to pass any instantiated derived class as a reference or pointer to IArray you can't benefit from polymorphism as you would need to downcast before adding or retrieving any contained values.  (Because IArray cannot define a getter or setter function without declaring the type to be got or set, and that type depends on which derived class was instantiated.)

Why can't the base class be templated?  The "base" class should be CustomArray, and the "derived" classes could arguably be typedefs.

And why not use std::vector?  (Possibly, for the practice.)